# Read windows phone primary e-mail address

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How do you get the Windows Phone **primary e-mail** address (or a list of e-mail addresses) ?

In my application I need to ask for users email address for reports. But I want to prefill the email box so that users does not have to enter it. How can I read his primary email address.

I know this can be easily done in **Android**. Using AccountManager (API level 5+).

I googled it but could not find any relevant reference. Kindly help I am new to windows phone development.

Comment: Hey there , I am new to windows phone development. Rather than simply down voting please guide why is my Question wrong ?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Same question for android got upvoted . Just because my current reputation is low does not mean that you get the right to down vote any question. See Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              get the Windows Phone primary e-mail address ...?
```

Not Possible, **Due to privacy concerns it is not possible to retrieve the account ID**

There are few links that are saying No.

[From MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/74490034-6d82-4b53-828e-c57c764a0b94/wp7-users-accounts-data-and-phone-number-c-?forum=wpdevelop)

[From SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510355/get-windows-phone-user-accounts) & [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387521/access-users-microsoft-account-email-id-from-my-app-in-windows-phone-8?answertab=votes#tab-top)

These Sources are bit older. But in latest update of Windows Phone it may possible.